# Why my jstree icon is not changing even though specifying it in the settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

i have a `jstree` for which i wanted to use some other icon rather then the **default** icon,

**what i have tried is:**

specified `icon` in the setting as `types`

```
"types" : {
   "default" : { "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" }
 },
```

even though it is not working

**below is demo (still folder icon is appearing):**

```js
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "data" : "A node",
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "types" : {
           "default" : { "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" }
         },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go this code works with the latest version of the jstree one thing that you should include is the link to font-awesome or if you have to use glyphicon then have to include its library, cause its not free therefore use font-awesome for the purpose

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jsTree test</title>
  <!-- 1 load Font-awesome css>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- 3 setup a container element -->
  <div id="jstree">
  </div>

  <!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "core" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "data" : "A node",
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "types" : {
           "default" : { "icon" : "fa fa-cloud" }
         },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "types"]
    });
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried your code but tree is not appearing, see fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg3B/2139/

Comment: even included latest `jstree` cdn  by you

Comment: Kindly mark it answered if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the `types` plugin:

```
"plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "types" ]
```

Additionally, it appears [`icon` should be an *object*](https://old.jstree.com/documentation/types), not a string:

> You can set an icon key - *it should be an object consisting of two
>   keys* - image (string - location of the image to be used as an icon) &
>   position (string - left and top pixels of the image - 10px 40px, only
>   useful when using sprites - omit otherwise).

It looks like you mixed up APIs from the current version and your version, `v1.0pre`.

Comment: tried though it is not working, what i missed can you please tell me, here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg3B/2133/